# Netzke confirmation popup

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, netzke

In **Netzke Grid** while deleting a record a **confirmation** is asked.
How can we implement the same for apply and save actions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. The model is simple countries table with country code and name. The important part is in `js_configure` method.

```
class Countries < Netzke::Basepack::Grid

  def configure(c)
    super
    c.model = 'Country'
    c.persistence = true
    c.columns = [
      { name: :code, width: 100 },
      { name: :name, header: 'Country Name', width: 300 }
    ]
  end

  js_configure do |c|
    c.init_component = <<-JS
      function() {
        var t = this;
        t.callParent();

        t.onApply = (function() {
          t._onApply = t.onApply;
          return function() {
            Ext.Msg.confirm(t.i18n.confirmation,
            t.i18n.areYouSure, function(btn) {
              if (btn == 'yes') {
                t._onApply();
              }
            })
          }
        })();
      }
    JS
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the kind reply and sorry for the late update. Everything is fine except saving changes to DB.

Comment: Sorry. I was busy and not able to answer sooner.

Comment: Please check the revised answer.

Comment: Great work! This works pretty well for me. Thanks for the great support